# Get-ADUser - extracting inactive and account that never logon

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a script to extract accounts that are inactive: not logon for more than 1 months or never logon. I have problem on extracting accounts that never logon.

Below is my script and $NotLogonCutoff is today -30 days:

```
$inactUsrdraft += @(Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -Filter 'PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and LastLogonTimeStamp -le $NotLogonCutoff' -Properties Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonTimeStamp,Description,passwordneverexpires,canonicalName | Select Name,SamAccountName,@{N='LastLogonTimeStamp'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)}},Description,passwordneverexpires,canonicalName | Sort Name)
```

I notice it doesn't extract user who never logon. But when I remove the "-and LastLogonTimeStamp -le $NotLogonCutoff" for investigation, the user that never logon have LastLogonTimeStamp "01/01/1601", I am not sure why this date is not LE than my date.

Could someone able to provide some assistants?

Answer (score 0):

The `LastLogonTimestamp` property contains the unmodified value of the AD attribute `lastLogonTimestamp`, which stores the date as a [`FileTime`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188768) value (a 64-bit integer). Your `$NotLogonCutoff` variable on the other hand probably contains a `DateTime` value.

Either convert `LastLogonTimestamp` to a `DateTime` value:

```
[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)
```

or use the `LastLogonDate` property, which already holds the converted value.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $user = Get-ADUser -Identity foo -Property *
PS C:\> $user | select LastLogonTimestamp, LastLogonDate | fl

LastLogonTimestamp : 130649197631177528
LastLogonDate      : 05.01.2015 09:22:43
```

Empty `LastLogonDate` values can be handled by using a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
PS C:\> $user = Get-ADUser -Identity bar -Property *
PS C:\> $user | select LastLogonTimestamp, LastLogonDate | fl

LastLogonTimestamp :
LastLogonDate      :

PS C:\> $user | select LastLogonTimestamp, @{n='LastLogonDate';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime([int64]$_.LastLogonTimestamp)}} | fl

LastLogonTimestamp :
LastLogonDate      : 01.01.1601 01:00:00
```

Comment: Hi, It look like lastlogondate is introduced in Win 2008 R2, is it? I'm actually migrating my script from Win 2003 (using Quest tool) to 2008 R2 currently, not aware of this so I still using LastLogonTimeStamp.

Googled around and found LastLogonDate is the local date after conversion of LastLogonTimeStamp. Is there a need for me to confirm this conversion work correctly in my environment? Is there MS resources describing this property? (those info I found is from forum)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the FileTime & DateTime. I tested the LastLogonDate is accurate however it doesn't solve the problem for those who never logon because it is still blank in LastLogonDate and cannot be processed with the -LE operator.

I solve it by filter -Filter 'enabled -eq $true -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and whenCreated -le $CreationCutOff -and ((-not ( LastLogonDate -like "*")) -or LastLogonDate -le $NotLogonCutoff)'

Comment: @nlks It's easier to handle that case by forcing a "null" date via a calculated property. See updated answer.